# call a dot NET Console application from java get the error "The handle is invalid"

Tags: java, .net

I'm trying to run dot net console application via Java:

process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);

Got following error:

```
Main Program Exception: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid
 at System.ConsolePal.GetBufferInfo(Boolean throwOnNoConsole, Boolean& succeeded)
 at System.ConsolePal.Clear()
```

The dot NET Application trying to output some messages to the Console.

when running it directly via the console (windows) there is no problem:

Is anything I can do in Java code to prevent this error, since I don't have control with dot NET application.

Thanks.

Comment: Guesswork - the problem is that the JVM doesn't have a console so it can't be inherited by a process that needs it.  What does `System.console()` give you?

Comment: What is your `commandLine` variable set to? I am guessing that it isn't the full path to the executable, or one of the path separators (slashes) are wrong or something of that nature.

Comment: @passer-by I think that's the problem,  but how can I use the System.console() with the process?

Comment: Start your Java app from the command line and use java.exe rather than javaw.exe ?